# django many to many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models named Event and EventUser.

```
class EventUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        u = User.objects.get(pk=self.user_id)
        return u.username

class Event(models.Model):
    EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Food & Beverage'),
        (2, 'Party'),
        (3, 'Natural'),
        (4, 'Historical'),
        (5, 'Educational'),
        (6, 'Sportive'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='event_creator')
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(EventUser, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So, naturally ManyToManyField is creating new table using event_id and eventuser_id however, I want to use the username instead of eventuser_id. Or, it can stay like that if I can receive usernames instead of id's when I requested it.

What I'm trying to tell is that;

[image]

When I got users field I want to see usernames on response instead of ids like the above image.

Comment: Can you post your serializer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CustomRelationalField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) to display the usernames instead of ids like so:

```
class UserListingField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return '{}'.format(value.user.username)

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        # assumption, value is id of EventUser
        return value

class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserListingField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but, EventUser has no 'username' since its extended from default User model of django

Comment: @can sorry about that, I've made changes to the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot man, I just added read_only=true and now its working like a charm :)

Comment: Just one more question, to enable both read and write I have to override to_internal_value but I could't do that. can you help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129923/discussion-between-evans-murithi-and-can).